# Serializing GeoQuerySet

Tags: django, serialization, django-rest-framework

I am trying to send events nearby any location.
I take input from this serializer.

```
class LatLongCateSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    category_id = serializers.IntegerField()
    latitude = serializers.DecimalField(max_digits=30,decimal_places=15)
    longitude = serializers.DecimalField(max_digits=30,decimal_places=15)
    distance = serializers.IntegerField()
```

then i try to get events from this post view inheriting from APIView of django rest framework, like this:

```
class NearbyEvents(APIView):
    serializer_class = LatLongCateSerializer

    def get_serializer_class(self):
        return self.serializer_class

    def get_event_serializer(self):
        return EventSerializer

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        serializer = self.serializer_class(data=request.data)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            point = Point(float(request.data['latitude']), float(request.data['longitude']))
            events = Event.objects.filter(location_point__distance_lte=(point, D(km=int(request.data['distance']))))
            if events.exists():
                event_serializer = self.get_event_serializer()
                ev = event_serializer(data=events)
                if ev.is_valid():
                    return Response(ev.data, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
                else:
                    print ev.errors
            return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
        return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

my event serializer inherits from GeoFeatureModelSerializer

```
from rest_framework_gis.serializers import GeoFeatureModelSerializer
class EventSerializer(GeoFeatureModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Event
        geo_field = 'location_point'
```

error i get :

```
{u'non_field_errors': [u'Invalid data. Expected a dictionary, but got GeoQuerySet.']}
```

My event model:

```
from location_field.models.spatial import LocationField
class BaseProduct(TimeStamp):
    title = models.CharField(_('Title'), max_length=255)
    desc = models.TextField(_('Description'), null=True, blank=True)
    nearby_metro = models.CharField(_("Neraby Metro Station"), max_length=100, null=True, blank=True)
location_point = LocationField(based_fields=[address], zoom=7, default='Point(1.0 1.0)')
    latitude = models.DecimalField(max_digits=30,decimal_places=15,null=True, blank=True)
    longitude = models.DecimalField(max_digits=30,decimal_places=15,null=True, blank=True)
```

Please guide me to correct solution.

Comment: Can you post your Event model.

Comment: @levi please check the models.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem is inner "serialization" process. Actually it's implemented using deserialization pattern which doesn't work of course. It should look something like this:

```
    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    serializer = self.serializer_class(data=request.data)
    if serializer.is_valid():
        point = Point(float(request.data['latitude']), float(request.data['longitude']))
        events = Event.objects.filter(location_point__distance_lte=(point, D(km=int(request.data['distance']))))
        if events.exists():
            event_serializer = self.get_event_serializer()
            ev = event_serializer(events, many=True)
            return Response(ev.data, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
        return Response(status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
    return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

Answer (score 0):

`ev = event_serializer(data=events)` should be

`ev = event_serializer(data=events,many=True)`